# Unable to access location with geckoDriver with browser version 119 and above

Tags: selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

```
    // FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    // FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    // profile.setPreference("permissions.default.desktop-notification", 1);

    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.addPreference("geo.enabled", true);
    options.addPreference("geo.provider.use_corelocation", true);
    //options.addPreference("media.navigator.permission.disabled", false);
    //options.addPreference("geo.prompt.testing", true);
    //options.addPreference("geo.prompt.testing.allow", true);

    // options.addPreference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", true);
    // options.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", True);
    // options.setProfile(profile);

    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
    driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/geolocation");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@onclick=\"getLocation()\"]")).click();
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a)[2]")).click();
    
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    
    driver.quit();
}
```

same is worrking with other drivers, using windows 11, Firefox 119.0.1 (64-bit), Java 11